# setInterval() only fires once

Tags: javascript, global-variables, setinterval

```js
var x = 0;

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
        setInterval(changeValue, 1000, "up");
        break;
    case "ArrowRight":
        setInterval(changeValue, 1000, "down");
        break;
    }
})

function changeValue(direction) {
    switch (direction) {
    case "up":
        x += 10;
        console.log(x);
        break;
    case "down":
        x -= 10;
        console.log(x);
        break;
    }
}
```

I was expecting my code to keep adding or subtracting 10 from `x` every second depending on what arrow key the user has pressed. However, `setInterval` only seems to fire once, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Works fine on my end (though you probably want to call `clearInterval` after another keystroke)

Comment: wrong usage of `setInterval` method ; at each keydown it creates a new setInterval process

Answer (score 0):

A way to do what you are looking for:

```js
var 
  conterVal = 0
, addValue  = -10
, refIntv   = null
  ;
bt_tenMoreLess.onclick =_=>
  {
  addValue = -addValue
  if (!refIntv)
    {
    counter.textContent = conterVal += addValue
    refIntv = setInterval( changeValue , 1000)
    bt_stop.disabled = false
    }
  }
bt_stop.onclick =_=>
  {
  clearInterval( refIntv )
  refIntv = null
  bt_stop.disabled = true
  }
function changeValue()
  { counter.textContent = conterVal += addValue }
```

```html
<p id="counter">0</p>
<button id="bt_tenMoreLess">count ± 10</button> 
<button id="bt_stop" disabled >stop</button>
```